# What does "I’m going to need a ‘booka" mean?

Tags: word-meaning

The context:

> But there is a greater truth. It is fun. Anyone who knew Chas just shakes their head, still in disbelief. My Godfather, my Uncle, Chas, was played by Ben Affleck. Ben Affleck… as Chas. Of all the &@$#. **I’m going to need a ‘booka.** To Chas …

Source: https://barrettsportsmedia.com/2021/12/15/the-truth-about-storytelling-is-on-display-in-the-tender-bar/

Comment: **Very** possibly, an alternative spelling of *'buca*, as in [sambuca](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sambuca)?

Comment: This actually seems quite likely to me, given the context.